# Perl regular expression substitution with groups

Tags: regex, linux, perl, ksh

I have the following JSON input

```
... "somefield":"somevalue", "time":"timevalue", "anotherfield":"value" ...
```

inside my KornShell (`ksh`) script, and I wish to replace timevalue with my value. So I created this regular expression using groups with works just fine

```
data=`cat somefile.json`
echo $data | perl -pe "s|(.*time\"\s*\:\s*\").*?(\".*)|\1%TIME%\2|g" | another-script.sh

... "somefield":"somevalue", "time":"%TIME%", "anotherfield":"value" ...
```

However ... I cannot use number as substitution because Perl uses numbers to define groups .. so this one obviously doesn’t work:

```
perl -pe "s|(.*time\"\s*\:\s*\").*?(\".*)|\120:00:00\2|g"
```

I can overcome this by doing a two-step substitution,

```
perl -pe "s|(.*time\"\s*\:\s*\").*?(\".*)|\1%TIME%\2|g" | perl -pe "s|%TIME%|20:00:00|"

... "somefield":"somevalue", "time":"20:00:00", "anotherfield":"value" ...
```

but I am sure there is a better and more elegant way to do it.

Comment: The better and more elegant way is to use a JSON parser...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perl doesn't use `\1` for substitution. If you had enabled warnings (e.g., with `perl -w`), Perl would have told you it's `$1`. Which can be disambiguated from surrounding digits by adding `{` `}`:

```
perl -pe 's|(.*time"\s*:\s*").*?(".*)|${1}20:00:00$2|g'
```

(I also removed all the redundant backslashes from the regex.)

On another note, what's the point of matching `.*` if you're just going to replace it by itself? Couldn't it just be

```
perl -pe 's|(time"\s*:\s*").*?(")|${1}20:00:00$2|g'
```

?

I'm not a big fan of `.*` or `.*?`. If you're trying to match the inside of a quoted string, it would be better to be specific:

```
perl -pe 's|(time"\s*:\s*")[^"]*(")|${1}20:00:00$2|g'
```

We're not trying to validate the input string, so now there's really no reason to match that final `"` (and replace it by itself) either:

```
perl -pe 's|(time"\s*:\s*")[^"]*|${1}20:00:00|g'
```

If your Perl is not ancient (5.10+), you can use `\K` to "keep" leading parts of the string, i.e. not include it in the match:

```
perl -pe 's|time"\s*:\s*"\K[^"]*|20:00:00|g'
```

Now only the `[^"]*` part will be substituted, saving us from having to do any capturing.

Comment: This is great!, I tried the $1 first but I missed the escaping and then changed to use the \1 (which now I understand is wrong).
Without escaping ,it doesn't work for me. perl -w -pe "s|(.*time\"\s*\:\s*\").*?(\".*)|\${1}20:00:00\${2}|g". Your last solution using \K is great, I am defenatly going to use this one. Thanks alot!

Comment: @Nir The whole problem is that you're using double quotes around the code. When in doubt, always use single quotes in the shell (unless you want to interpolate variables).

Answer (score 7):

Whilst you *could* do this with regexes, it would be so much easier with [the right tool](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
jq '.time="20:00:00"' somefile.json
```

If you particularly wish to use Perl, the core Perl distribution has included a JSON parser since 2011, so you could do something like:

```
perl -MJSON::PP=decode_json,encode_json -0 -E '$j = decode_json(<>); $j->{time} = "20:00:00"; say encode_json($j)' somefile.json
```

Comment: That should be `-0777`, not `-0` (assuming you want to slurp the whole input). `-0` sets the input line terminator to `"\0"`, not `undef`.

Comment: Also, `perl -MJSON::PP -p0777 -e '$_ = encode_json { %{decode_json $_}, time => "20:00:00" }` for compactness.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my version does not support this "Can't locate JSON/PP.pm in @INC". I have no permissions to update or install anything so I can't use jq

Comment: Are you on a RedHat-based distro? Some of them split out standard Perl packages in annoying ways. Often there's a `perl-full` or similarly named package that gives you everything. `JSON::PP` has been standard since Perl 5.14.

Comment: IIRC it's `perl-core` on older RedHats.